# DataGridView - update value dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to update the values of my DataGridView cells dynamically when the row header is pressed.

The value updates but the view doesn't refresh.

```
void OnRowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var databaseRecordId = e.RowIndex;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = false;
}
```

Simple solution please?

Comment: the problem is only in CheckBoxColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and it works.

```
private void dgvNews_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
        var databaseRecordId = e.RowIndex;
        dgvNews.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "AAAAAA";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put this after the update:

dataGridView1.refresh();

Just to see if it helps, otherwise I have several other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value = false;
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

or:

```
dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value = false;
dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.
I tried a datasource that is a DataTable or a list of objects.

What is the type of your datasource ?

I'm afraid you are using anonymous types as a datasource , keep in mind that it is read-only and thus you can't update It.

You can use a dataTable or I can provide you with a method that converts anonymous types to datatable.

This Doesn't Work :

```
            List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "A", Path = "1" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "B", Path = "2" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "C", Path = "3" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "D", Path = "4" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "E", Path = "5" });

dataGridView1.DataSource = (from a in myList select new
                                        {
                                            URL = a.URL,
                                            Path = a.Path
                                        }).ToList();

private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
            var databaseRecordId = e.RowIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = 555;
}
```

While this works **( Edited with Boolean Column )**

```
DataTable x = new DataTable();
            x.Columns.Add("URL");
            x.Columns.Add("PAth");
            x.Columns.Add("Boolean");

            x.Rows.Add("A", "1", true);
        x.Rows.Add("B", "1" , false);
        x.Rows.Add("C", "1" , true);
        x.Rows.Add("D", "1" , true);
        x.Rows.Add("E", "1", true);
        x.Rows.Add("F", "1", true);
        x.Rows.Add("G", "1",true);

dataGridView1.DataSource = x;


    private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var databaseRecordId = e.RowIndex;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = false;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the problem is only with bool type.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what you mean . Do you mean you can update String types in an anonymous types  datasource ?

Comment: try with DataTable with Boolean-Column, see the result.

Comment: I just tried it and it works. No Need for Refresh() or RefreshEdit() also.

Comment: change this `x.Columns.Add("Boolean")` to             `x.Columns.Add("Boolean", typeof(bool));` and try again.

Comment: the checkbox becomes unchecked **Immediately**? befor you select another row? in my computer, NO.

Comment: Sure! The event is RowHeaderMouseClick.